# How do I extract a string between two characters using ADFs expression builder?

Tags: azure, expression, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to extract part of a file name using expressions in ADF expression builder. The part I'm trying to extract is dynamic in size but always appears between "_" and "-".

How can I go about doing this extraction?

Thanks!

Comment: Pipeline expression or Data Flow expression?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there's a pipeline parameter named filename, you could use the below expression to extract value between '_' and '-', e.g. input 'ab_cd-', you would get 'cd' as output:

```html
@{substring(pipeline().parameters.fileName, add(indexOf(pipeline().parameters.fileName, '_'),1),sub(indexOf(pipeline().parameters.fileName, '-'),3))}
```

You may want to check the documentation of Expressions and functions in Azure Data Factory for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#string-functions