# Regex Additional Column in Copy Activity Azure Data Factory

Tags: string, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am trying to parse the `$$FILEPATH` value in the "Additional columns" section of the Copy Activity.

The filepaths have a format of: time_period=202105/part-12345.parquet . I would like just the "202105" portion of the filepath. I cannot hardcode it because there are other time_period folders.

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819603/how-do-i-extract-a-string-between-two-characters-using-adfs-expression-builder) (from the link below): `@{substring($$FILEPATH, add(indexOf($$FILEPATH, '='),1),sub(indexOf($$FILEPATH, '/'),6))}` but I get an error saying **Unrecognized expression: $$FILEPATH**

The only other things I can think of are using: 1) Get Metadata Activity + For each Activity or 2) possibly trying to do this in DataFlow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$FILEPATH` is the reserved variable to store the file path. You cannot add dynamic expression with `$$FILEPATH`.

You have to **create a variable** to store the folder name as required and then pass it dynamically in an additional column.

Below is what I have tried.

1. As your folder name is not static, getting the folder names using the `Get Metadata` activity.

[image]

**Get Metadata Output:**

[image]

2. Pass the output to the `ForEach` activity to loop all the folders.

[image]

3. Add a **variable** at the pipeline level to store the folder name.

[image]

4. In the `ForEach` activity, add the `set variable` activity to extract the date part from the folder name and add the value to the variable.

   ```
   @substring(item().name, add(indexof(item().name, '='),1), sub(length(item().name), add(indexof(item().name, '='),1)))
   ```

[image]

**Output of Set variable:**

[image]

5. In **source dataset**, parameterize the path/filename to pass them dynamically.

[image]

6. Add `copy data` activity after set variable and select the source dataset.

a)  Pass the **current item name** of the `ForEach` activity as a file path. Here I hardcoded the filename as `*.parquet` to copy all files from that path (this works only when all files have the same structure).

b)  Under Additional Column, add a new column, give a name to a new column, and under value, select to **Add dynamic content** and add the existing variable.

[image]

7. Add **Sink dataset** in Copy data Sink. I have added the Azure SQL table as my sink.

[image]

8. In **Mapping**, add filename (new column) to the mappings.

[image]

9. When you run the pipeline, the ForEach activity runs the number of items in the Get Metadata activity.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU!! I think I am really close. I get an error on Step 8. My container structure has an additional level and I'm not sure how to include that level with the dynamic variable, @item().name. I cannot preview data nor import mapping. Here is what I'm seeing: https://ibb.co/FzbWn9S

Comment: Can you try using concat in the expression. Add dynamic content--> @concat('kpi_test/', item().name)

Comment: THAT WORKED!! Thank you thank you! Wow that's great! Your answer is so detailed -it is much appreciated!! Thanks again https://ibb.co/qrHF4JC

Comment: You have no idea how often this will be reapplied! :) How did you learn ADF? A course, building, reading?