# Add Azure Blob Partitions to Azure SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-sql

I have partitioned parquet files in Azure Blob that I am copying to Azure SQL. How do I get the partition name into the SQL table?

I've figured out how to get the full file path into the SQL table by adding an Additional Column in the source data section of the Copy Activity (image 1 & 2), but I'm trying to figure out how to regex the full file path down to just the partition name (202105).

In the data preview for the source data in the Copy Activity, it shows the time_period column with just the partition name (image 3). But when it shows up in SQL it is NULL for all rows (or it's the full file path, depending on if I added Additional Columns in the source data section of the Copy Activity).

**Image 1:**
[image: Image 1 of using $$FILEPATH]

**Image 2:**
[image: Image 2 of setting parameter for filepath]

**Image 3:**
[image: showing that the column shows up in preview]

I've tried changing the data type for time_period to an INT in Azure SQL. I've tried parsing the `$$FILEPATH`, but nothing I've tried has worked.

I'm basically starting from scratch as I'm sure there's a better.
Extra background [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/582075/error-2200-copy-activity-partitioned-parquet-colum.html) and possibly [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/585056/add-azure-blob-partitions-to-azure-sql-table.html).

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56819603/how-do-i-extract-a-string-between-two-characters-using-adfs-expression-builder)

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#:%7E:text=enablePartitionDiscovery) in MS doc, you can utilize `enablePartitionDiscovery` feature.

**Source**: partitioned files:

[image]

**Source Dataset:**

Just mentioned the container name and leave the directory and file fields empty. We shall filter them using `WildCard paths` in Copy Activity.

[image]

Configure source in `Copy Activity` with respect to your files path:

**Note:** you can skip the **step 4** i.e. additional column with `$$FILEPATH`, just shown for reference. You can drop this bit as you already get the ready column using `enablePartitionDiscovery`.

[image]

For a single folder to be picked, you will set as below.

**Wildcard paths:** `sink / columnparts / time_period=202105 / *.parquet`

For multiple folders `time_period=202105` , `time_period=202106` ..... as seen in previous sinp, set as below.

**`**`** will take the place of any folder in the parent folder `columnparts`

**Wildcard paths:** `sink / columnparts / ** / *.parquet`

**Partition root Path**: This should point to the parent folder where all the partitioned folders rest.

In my example: `sink/columnparts`

partition root path must be provided when you enable partition discovery.

[image]

**Sink:** Optional update existing table or just create a new one.

[image]

**View from SQL DB:** `time_period` column holds the value `202105`

```
time_period=202105/part-00004-fcbe0bf5-2c93-45f5-9bb2-2f9089a3e83a-c000.snappy.parquet
```

[image]

If you see this error:

[image]

You have a mapping that is not updated! In the mapping section, you can `clear` or `reset` schema and `Import schema` again just to be sure.

In my case it was additional column `file_path`

[image]

**--OR--**

`$$FILEPATH` is a reserved variable, you cannot use it in expression builder or in functions to manipulate.

Instead if you can incorporate a step after you copy to SQL DB i.e. use a stored procedure as below.

Where column `path` holds the full file path received from `$$FILEPATH` as you have managed already. `StoreParquetTest` is the table created in SQL `sink`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE trimpath
AS
    UPDATE StoreParquetTest
    SET path = SUBSTRING(path,(CHARINDEX('=',path) + 1), ((CHARINDEX('/',path) - CHARINDEX('=',path) -1)))
GO
```

Now you can use the stored procedure activity in Pipeline after Copy Activity.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there no way to use the enable partition discovery feature?

Comment: Absolutely, thats the best way you can use, let me add that above too

Comment: I get this error saying ParquetColumnNotFound: https://ibb.co/HgNPwRb . The source dataset's file structure is root/source_name/partitions. So in your example, I have the source dataset's file path as sink/columnparts and the "file" field is empty. I also tried sink/columnpats/**

Comment: sink/columnpats/** is in case of my example. In your case you would have to modify. The `Wildcards Path` field should point to the parquet files. I have updated more details in answer, please try and let me know